# java web service wsdl: Getting data out of a responce variable

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

Very new to web services (as you can tell from the Q) so i am pretty sure this is a basic question.

I am sending the request of to the server

```
ExecuteSQLQueryReq sqlParams = new ExecuteSQLQueryReq();
sqlParams.setSql(sqlState.getNoDevInDP("LIV_Phones_DP"));
```

and getting the response i expect:

```
ExecuteSQLQueryRes getSqlResult = axlPort.executeSQLQuery(sqlParams);
```

i can see all the data is there in the object from the eclipse debugging
[image]

but from the object "getSqlResult" i dont know how to pull the data out. The response is in the following format:
[image]

Any help would be great

Thanks
Alexis

EDIT:
Screen shot of "ExecuteSQLQueryRes". The only methods i see is to return a list of Objects, which i do and that the screenshot of the variables in eclipse you mention. Its the next step .... how to get from a generic Object the data out..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the type signatures, I'd say you would invoke the service like so:

```
List<Object> rows = axlPort.executeSQLQuery(sqlParams)
                           .getReturn()
                           .getRow();
for(Object row : rows) {
    Element rowElement = (Element) row;
    // utilize DOM API
}
```

As far as I can tell from the information posted you're getting a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of [Elements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html). In XML:

```
<row>?</row>
<row>?</row>
<row>?</row>
```

Since `row` is [anyType](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#anyType) nothing specific can be inferred about its structure. In the specific case, the first entry looks like this assuming a single child (text) node:

```
<row>339</row>
```

You can use the [Java DOM APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/index.html) to access the data.

*From the name onwards, this service looks like it just exposes the underlying database implementation. Consider adhering to stricter SOA principles if you have any influence over the service design.*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess the part i am getting stuck on is converting/parse the variable "getSqlResult" into a "Document Object" or even if that's the way i should be trying to access the data in the variable..

Comment: You have not provided any information on the `ExecuteSQLQueryRes` type. That looks like an Eclipse screenshot. Highlight the `ExecuteSQLQueryRes` type and press F3 (Open Declaration) to see the available methods and type hierarchy.

Comment: Have updated the problem description with the screenshot of methods and type. The class `ExecuteSQLQueryRes` was generated using  `wsimport`

Comment: thanks for your help and patient on this. I am just getting back into java after a long time away :-)